# Adjust column width given dictionary with column headers and desired width

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I have 'column_widths' dictionary which includes column headers and desired column width.
When printed, it returns:

```
{'Code': 9, 'Invest Style': 15, 'Total': 11, 'Incept': 11}
```

I'm struggling to write code to utilize this information and adjust column widths of the Excel file so that when the final file is opened it displays all data without the need to manually adjust column width to show more characters.

```
#reorganize column layout 
desired_layout = ['Code','Invest Style','Total','Incept']
df_base = df_base.reindex(columns=desired_layout)

#create a list with max lenght of a string in each column
max_characters_list = []
for column in df_base:
    max_value = df_base[column].astype(str).str.len().max() +1
    max_characters_list.append(max_value)

#create dictionary with column headers and column width
column_widths = dict(zip(desired_layout,max_characters_list))

#launch openpyxl
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(output_file)
worksheet = workbook.active

#loop to adjust column width
for column, size in column_widths.items():
    worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = size

#save file
workbook.save('output.xlsx')
```

The code above (loop) works if I substitute column_widths with a manual entry for each column- this isn't optimal thought because there are times when columns B and C will have longer strings in them than 15 & 11.

```
column_widths = {'A': 9,
                 'B': 15,
                 'C': 11
         'D': 11}
```

Comment: Column widths are difficult but you probably just need to be a bit more generous. BTW. I wouldn't use pandas to get the column widths, just do it in openpyxl.